# Move multiple photos in a single operation from AutoBackup to album in Google Photos

Tags: google-plus-photos

I have Auto Backup turned on my phone. It uploads the photos. I navigate on my desktop to:

https://plus.google.com/u/0/photos/search/%23AutoBackup

I see I can select multiple photos. There is a `More` dropdown. It is there that I expected to be able to move or copy these multiply selected photos into a chosen album. But such does not exist.

Was this just never implemented or am I missing something obvious?

Note, I can click on each one of the photos and move them one by one to an album, but that is unproductive.